# How can I callback JavaScript Object properties with passing argument?

Tags: javascript

```
function DarkWorld(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.speed = 7;
        this.energyLevel = 10;
        this.flyAbility = true;
        this.description = function () {
            retun(this.name + " has the capability to hold the hummer");
        };
    }
```

I have the above JavaScript code and trying to create a call back function that accepts argument, and access the properties of object.

For example: I want to pass a name to the object and access the `energyLevel` to print on screen.

Comment: what do you mean by object? you mean `DarkWorld`?

Comment: Shouldn't line 7 be `return this.name + "";` ?

Comment: `return` is not a function. And just update the function to `return this.name + ...`

Comment: @AliGajani fixed. But how can I access the property of the Object?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you're exactly trying to do?

Comment: @AliGajani For example: I want to print the energyLevel of the object.

Comment: just with `this.energyLevel`, at least when you created darkWorld like `var darkWorld = new DarkWorld('LOTR');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two ways of doing this:

you either run your DarkWorld function in the parameter, or you create a new instance:

assuming this is your other function:

```
function run(darkworld) {
  alert(darkworld.name);
  alert(darkworld.speed);
}

//this one is questionable now... it was working but now its not
//this will work if you add "return self" or "return this" in your-
  //DarkWorld object
run(DarkWorld('apple'));

//or

var dw = new DarkWorld('apple');
run(dw);
```

***update***

you should probably do this too, for the first method to work:

```
function DarkWorld(name) {
    //thank you icepickle for pointing this out to me
    if (typeof this === 'undefined' || !(this instanceof DarkWorld)) {
        return new DarkWorld(name);
    }
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.speed = 7;
    self.energyLevel = 10;
    self.flyAbility = true;
    self.description = function () {
        retun self.name + " has the capability to hold the hummer";
    };
}
```

Comment: what would be `this` in the first example of your `run(DarkWorld('apple'));` and would this still work with strict mode on?

Comment: this is in the DarkWorld function (or object), so it should reference that... or maybe not.

Comment: without the new keyword in your first example? I see it rather as undefined or global scope? (hence the remark on strict mode)

Comment: @Icepickle hmm.. not sure, it's working in jsfiddle for me. idk about strict mode though

Comment: with `'use strict'` it will still throw an error, because `this` is undefined ;) see here: https://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/2xujz30a/ 
Strict mode adds some very cool stuff for javascript, and one of that is that this is undefined in global scope, and the first one, is on global scope, I find the pattern questionable, as there you never know what this might be ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103234/discussion-between-icepickle-and-abdul-ahmad).